# react old state is showing data in new url page?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have List page where list of posts are displaying by calling the action in componentDidMount method. Links are also displayed so that when user click it will show that particular post. But when new page/url is rendered it shows the list of all posts without fetching, but when we refresh the page it does not show the list. What it means that the state data is visible to new page.
How it occurs because in react state clears when url is changed ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5Mpx.png)

Comment: please do not add code as images. add it to the question itself. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> How it occurs because in react state clears when URL is changed?
>   This is true and not true, actually depends on what context you are looking at. In here react state(the component state will clear) when the component is unmounted or when you deliberately.
>   So possible places you should look at it are:

1. check whether you are checking somewhere that data is fetched and you don't need to make the call. some flag in your reducer that is not being reset.
2. Are you using any kind of data persistence, while reloading? like saving in session storage or local storage.
3. Try to add debugger in componentDidMount and this.props.fetchPost function and see if those are being called

Comment: If i removed method calls and connect to action in single post page, still all posts can be accessed first time. Also i am not using any session storage or local storage. Simply in List page action is called and state updated and list is shown, and when click any post i used Link to="/post/id" to naviage to new page.